SAP CAPM React JS Deployed application getting http 404 after routing to 2nd page
SAP CAPM Managed App router React JS application working fine in HomePage as it takes the guid but, when navigation to other page is triggered then HTTP calls/Network Calls doesn't work..
getting 404 error.
Managed App router Deployed Application

1st Page HTTP calls working fine

2nd Page HTTP calls getting 404 error


Note: Application is working fine in localhost...

I implemented the routing after following below tutorial and it worked :)
seems SAP Only supports HashRouter
enter link description here
